# How to report bugs for TA-Lib?

Tags: node.js, ta-lib

I found the algorithm of SAR is incorrect: the value maybe in the range of `High` and `Low`, there is no email or forum(Sorry, SMF was unable to connect to the database. This may be caused by the server being busy. Please try again later.) to report it. Any one could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ticket for bug on official project page at sourceforge:
https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/bugs/?source=navbar

Also, could you explain the problem right here? I have a fork of ta-lib and would like to check if problem exists in my code.